# Is this script vulnerable to command injection?

Tags: bash, security, code-injection

I have the following script that I can run as root in a server with sudo:

```
#!/bin/bash
export filename=`echo $1`
grep -i "word" $filename
```

I suspect that this script is vulnerable to command injection, is this the case?

However, when I put something as "test ;id" as an argument of the script with sudo (e.g. sudo myScript.sh test; id). The "id" command is running but with my user access right not as root.

Comment: Double quote the `$filename` in the last line.

Comment: Try using `'-r /'` as the argument.

Comment: The `echo $1` is the vulnerable point for me. As it stands that is pointless, so I assume it is something more complex in reality. Put quotes round the `"$1"` as suggested.

Comment: Use [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to find many code problems, including command injection vulnerabilities.  It finds several problems with the example code.  One problem that it does not find is the inability to handle filenames that begin with '-'.  A fully safe 'grep command is `grep -i -- word "filename"`.  See [Bash Pitfalls #3 (Filenames with leading dashes)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Filenames_with_leading_dashes).